# How to make this function smaller?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to optimize the below function by removing the variables being sent to the htttp.post and putting them in an array. Is this possible?

Putting the variables in a normal array but  I get the boolean error.

```
  getUsers(val) {
    this.spinner.show();
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('x-access-token', this.currentUser.token),
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
    };
    return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + val, { status: this.userAdvanceSearch.status, email: this.userAdvanceSearch.email, filterWithin: this.filterQuery, name: this.userAdvanceSearch.name, userTypeNo: this.authenticationService.getCurrentUserType().userTypeNo }, options).subscribe((res: any) => {
      val === 'pdf' ? this.blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' }) : this.blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'text' });
      const downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      link.href = downloadURL;
      val === 'pdf' ? link.download = 'users.pdf' : link.download = 'users.csv';
      link.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL);
      this.spinner.hide();
    });
  }
```

This works as is, but I want it to be cleaner and shorter if possible.

Comment: It seems like Angular code, if so why not using service file to abstract your HTTP request?

Answer (score 2):

This will be much more better you reduce the work load for service and only use service to make API call. In the component you will subscribe and do some logic calculation

```
getUsers(val) {
    const options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('x-access-token', this.currentUser.token),
        responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
    };

    let data = { status: this.userAdvanceSearch.status, 
        email: this.userAdvanceSearch.email, 
        filterWithin: this.filterQuery, 
        name: this.userAdvanceSearch.name, 
        userTypeNo: this.authenticationService.getCurrentUserType().userTypeNo 
    }

    return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + val, data, options);
}

someMethod() {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.someService.getUsers(val).subscribe((res: any) => {
        val === 'pdf' ? this.blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' }) : this.blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'text' });
        const downloadURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(res);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = downloadURL;
        val === 'pdf' ? link.download = 'users.pdf' : link.download = 'users.csv';
        link.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadURL);
    });
    this.spinner.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a Class to describe the data you want to send e.g.

```
export class DataRequest {
   status: string;
   email:string;
   ...
}
```

Your method ->

```
dataRequest = new DataRequest();
dataRequest.status = this.userAdvanceSearch.status;
...
return this.http.post(this.apiRoot + val, dataRequest)....
```